# Ionic List Reorder - Can’t drop at same spot as beginning

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

When I want to reorder an ionic list and grab an item, I can’t hold it and place it back at the same position.
So when I drag the top item and decide I didn’t want to reorder that one, I have to put it in any other spot first, before I can put it back.

This is very annoying, because I want to put it where-ever I want. If the “indexes.from” and “indexes.to” are the same, I just don’t want to do anything.

Is there any way to hack/change this behaviour? I've also posted this on te Ionic Forum.

Scenario also happens in the demo in the Ionic docs:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/item/ItemReorder/

Comment: Hope you can ask this as a feature: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues

Comment: Good point; I've added the feature request: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/12940